# Is there a tab-enabled CLI for Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line

I'm looking for a terminal for Windows that supports tabs, maybe splitting and I'd love to be able to autocomplete and double tap the tab key to list files like in Linux terminals. Is there such a great CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)?

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font, different window styles